# Should we learn Window Form before WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

Is there a learning curve? I want to pick up Windows Form but when reading many threads about WF vs WPF, I was totally persuaded by WPF. What should I do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just learn WPF and forget Windows Forms if you don't need it. Windows Forms and WPF are totally different so learning one of them does not really help with the other.

Comment: Exact. And if you want to learn quickly I recommend the Learn WPF MVVM book: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01M365NCZ

Answer (score 3):

WPF - I learned windows forms first and it is difficult to switch my mind to MVVM mode now when I build UI's. I personally wish that WPF was my first love.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to know Windows Forms in order to learn WPF. If you are going to code in C# or VB.NET and are running on modern hardware, I would go with WPF.

Answer (score 2):

There are no technical reasons why you'd want to learn Windows Forms before learning WPF. They are completely different technologies.

Unless you need to use Windows Forms to maintain an old application, stick with WPF.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

I assume you're working on a Windows application that must be installed on a client machine, Windows Forms and WPF would be good choices.

If you're starting an application from scratch, I would recommend WPF so focus on that.

If you have to maintain an existing application already written in Windows Forms, then you better learn Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not bad to first make a few application with Windows Form, that is classic way, and doing this you will not lose nothing because making application with Windows Form you just make classic application with standard UI. After this if you want that you application has better and nicer UI than go with WPF.

Answer (score 0):

My personal opinion is the the learning curve on WPF is a lot steeper if you want to get all the benefits of using MVVM, so it could also depend on how your development team is set up, with how many people and how complex your solutions are. You can of course just use WPF with all code behind, but you might as well use WinForms if this is all you want to do.

Comment: Even if used with an all-code-behind approach, WPF offers much richer experience from a UI point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Nope!
WPF is the latest trend. Winforms is not quite dead yet though...

If somebody wants to learn window application development. Starting from WPF will take him to the latest trend. Of course, Winform previous experience can be an advantage.